# How do i get only the first word of a string and then compare it to another in c?

Tags: c, string, file

I have to get the first word of a string in a file and compare it to some words and if they are the same as the word I compare it to it increments a counter to then display at the end with the quantity of each word.
I'm always getting the first two words in the right quantity and the others `0`, or all `0`.
I'd appreciate the help.

Tried doing it by doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fpl = fopen("your_file.txt", "r");
    if (fpl != NULL) {
        printf("File opened\n");

        char vetor[500];
        char firstword[11];
        int alamedas = 0;

        while (fgets(vetor, 500, fpl)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (vetor[i] == 'A' && vetor[i + 6] == 'a') {
                    int n = 0;
                    while (n < 7) {
                        firstword[n] = vetor[i];
                        i++;
                        n++;
                    }
                    firstword[n] = '\0';  
                    if (strcmp("Alameda", firstword) == 0) {
                        alamedas += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fclose(fpl);
        printf("Alamedas - %d\n", alamedas);
    } else {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then if I add another `if`, like the first `if` after the first `for`, it doesn't add to their own count don't know why.

Comment: You've not shown enough code. Likely problem is that the buffer `firstword` is _dirty_ and only works for the first case by luck. Have you read that **all** C strings are terminated with a NUL (`'\0'`)? Without that, `strcmp()` won't be doing what you think it is doing...

Comment: You can use either `sscanf` or `strtok` to extract the first word of a string.

Comment: appreciate it, i didn't have knowledge of sscanf, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- `fgets(vetor, 500, fpl)`

Assume, if a line in input file has more than `500` characters, in that case you will get incorrect output because, in next iteration, `fgets()` will read rest of the same line that it read in previous call.

- `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`

This `for` loop doesn't make any sense. After reading a line/string from file, this loop will search for all occurrence of a sub-string in `vetor` buffer (up to first `100` characters) which has current processing letter `A` and from that, the seventh letter is `a` and then copy those characters in another buffer and compare with string `"Alameda"`.
If your aim is to compare the first word of every line of a file with a word  then extract the first word from the buffer that has data read by `fgets()` and, to extract first word, ignore any whitespace character at the beginning of buffer and once an alphabet found, read till you find a whitespace character. Copy those alphabets in a buffer and compare with the word you want to count. You can also use `fscanf()` as an alternative to read first word of string, provided you know the correct format specifier to pass `fscanf()`.

To read a file and compare the first word of each line of file with a word and print the count of that word, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE * fp = fopen ("test.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char firstword[100];
    int alamedas = 0;

    while (fscanf(fp, "%99s%*[^\n]", firstword) == 1) {
        if (strcmp ("Alameda", firstword) == 0) {
            alamedas += 1;
        }
    }

    fclose (fp);
    printf("Alamedas - %d\n", alamedas);

    return 0;
}
```

Program is fairly straight forward except the `fscanf()` format specifier string - `"%99s%*[^\n]"`. In this format specifier, `%99s` will ignore the initial whitespace characters (if any) and then read the first word in buffer (number `99` means read maximum up to `99` characters if word is bigger than `99` characters, this is to prevent the buffer overflow) and `%*[^\n]` will ignore the rest of the line, up to a newline character.

If you want to search multiple words occurrence as a first word in lines of a file then it's better to create a structure with a string and an `int` member:

```
struct wc {
    char st[100];
    int cnt;
};
```

Create array of `struct wc` and initialize it's `st` member with word string and corresponding `cnd` with `0`:

```
struct wc arr[] = {{"Alameda", 0}, {"someword", 0}};
```

After extracting first word, compare that word with all the words in array `arr` in a loop and if it matches with any of the word, increase it's corresponding count. Once done with reading file, print the array `arr` members.

Let me know, if you have any further question.

Answer (score 1):

some comments on your code:

- you get data from file to `vetor[]` using `fgets()` function, it is justified if there is 1 word per string in your file, but it still looks a little bit messy. Much cleaner solution is to use `fscanf(fpl, "%s", vetor)` - this way it scans 1 word separated from others with space/newline/tab... . The next time you use this function it will read the next word, if there are no words left it will return 0 and while-loop will stop.
- ok, we have scanned the word, but how do we know if it is first or not? For that we can create a flag before the while loop:

```
    int first_word_readen = 0; 
    while (fscanf(...))
    {
        if (first_word_readen == 0)
        {
            strcpy(firstword, vetor); // copy string firstword = vetor
            first_word_readen = 1;    // so this "if" will never work again after 
        }                             // that
    
        if (strcmp("Alameda", vetor) == 0) // then you compare 
            alamedas += 1;
    }
```

- in the beginning of the code you have the following block:

```
    if (fpl != NULL) {
        printf("File opened\n");
    
        // ...
       } else {
         printf("Can't open file\n");
       }
```

You can simply make it more readable by just "inverting" it:

```
    if (fpl == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        return 0; // stop the program
    }
    // if "if" above didnt stop the program - it means that fpl != NULL
    printf("File opened\n");
    // your code
```

I hope i got the problem right, your first solution was a little bit straightforward, i would recommend to read about standart string.h functions such as `strcpy()` (btw. you have written your own one in your code :) ).
Also you have too much {{{{{}}}}}} brackets, which leads to very complex code unsustainable code. Try dividing your code into funcitons, and you will read it much easier.
Solutions should always be beautiful and pretty small! Good luck

Answer (score -1):

use strcmp function

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp

C strcmp()
The strcmp() compares two strings character by character. If the strings are equal, the function returns 0.